# Why did the Diggers choose to remain hidden?

Tags: seveneves

I just finished Seveneves and either I missed it or it wasn't addressed...

The leaders of the Diggers choose to push the "traitorous cowards" rhetoric and arouse hostility among their people towards the Spacers. Why? Greed for power? Misplaced caution? Some grudge?

Comment: Squatter's rights.  There's a line in there somewhere about the spacers abandoning the planet and no longer have any claim over the land.

Comment: @TGnat: That's a rhetoric they push but it's completely bogus to anyone who gives it half a thought. The military power aside, and the potential benefits aside, "Well, okay, we're taking our toys and leaving the surface to you. The aforementioned toys include the water, the atmosphere and all plant and animal life we have brought. Have fun. We'll claim Earth again once you're all dead. How's your supply of tungsten, by the way?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing definitive in the text to explain their behavior, but the most likely reason is **the need for opposition to form social cohesiveness**.

Let's face, the Diggers are in a tight corner.  They have been forced to live within a very narrow population band for centuries - they only have room/resources for so many to survive, and if there are too few then survival odds also plummet.  They've been shown to have a socially coercive system to maintain a precise population:

> More important for present purposes was to get a general understanding
>   of the Diggers' culture, and why they behaved as they did.
>
> The requirement for a steel-spined authoritarian culture was obvious. 
>   Any power structure one of whose main golas was to prevent humans from
>   [reproducing with] each other at will had to be extremely
>   formidable....  Structurally, culturally, it was very like a Bronze
>   Age theocracy, but without any trace of God or the supernatural.

What's the best way for the leaders to get their society to fall in line and follow rules?  To create enemies.  Who are the only natural enemies?  The people who went away, and who threaten to come back with more numbers than the Diggers:

> At some point the Committee - which was what they called their ruling
>   council - most have become aware that vast numbers of humans were
>   living in space and actively prosecuting the TeReForm.  They could
>   simply have walked out onto the surface and sent out some kind of SOS
>   at that point.  Instead **they had made a positive decision to conceal
>   themselves**, to hide their spoil dumps, to shun communication with the
>   Spacers.  The central question, then, was why they had made such a
>   choice.  Sonar Taxlaw wasn't much help in explaining it.  When Ty or
>   the others asked questions, she offered nonresponsive answers that
>   told of a subterranean culture in which such things were never spoken
>   of.
>
> It was clear, however, that having made that decision, the Committee
>   would have to **explain it, justify it, and perpetuate it by painting
>   the Spacers as alien mutants, and furthermore by cultivating a finely
>   developed sense of racial grievance** against the cowards who had run
>   away and abandoned them.

(Presumably the Pingers get a pass because they also stayed, have more limited numbers, and zero territorial conflict with the Diggers)

The 'steel-spined authoritarian culture' could reasonably expect a lot of upheaval once there was contact with (apparently more numerous) Spacers - and when there's upheaval, the people on top don't stay there.  So, where Stephenson explicitly states the answer isn't known, I think it comes down to the head Diggers fearing change and declaring an enemy to keep their people lined up behind them.

Page 802 seems to confirm this, speaking of the Digger that went along with the Spacers:

> "But you didn't..."
>
> "Abduct her?  No, she just tagged along."
>
> Sensing doubt, or at least curiosity, from the Ivyn, Ty continued:
>   "And more would do the same given the chance.  The transition to
>   surface life is putting their culture through a blender.  **Which is why
>   their leaders are being so reactionary.**"

(Quotes are from pages 796-797 and 802 of Seveneves)

Comment: I'm still not quite satisfied. I mean - yes, that would be logical for *retaining social cohesiveness*, but with the new situation in the world, does that social cohesiveness serve any purpose other than making everyone's lives miserable?

Comment: A bunch of new people showed up with more technology and have started using land.  Suffice it to say the Native Americans failed to maintain social cohesiveness in the face of the European invasion, and where are they now?  I'm not saying it'll _work_ - I'm saying the knee-jerk reaction of any society is to rally the troops around us vs. them.

Comment: So, in short - fear of change in general, and specifically fear of losing the leadership positions? Keeping the martial law necessary in the times of disaster and inventing a new threat to legitimize its existence long past when it outlived its purpose - just an authoritarian government grasping at straws to remain in control?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I made a minor edit ("What's the best way *for the leaders* to get their society to fall in line...") to clarify that I'm accusing the leaders of manipulating the situation here :)

Comment: *shrug* I don't understand the people who believe it's better to be the king of beggars than the poorest of millionaires. But they exist, and they do make sure none of their beggars ever becomes a millionaire.